# MYSQLI Extension Missing XAMPP for Windows

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This is **NOT** a duplicate question, as I stated...I've already tryed solutions found here on Stack overflow.  Most of the questions related to older versions of XAMPP and none of the solutions worked.  Hence the reason I posted this..it's a newer version of XAMPP and pretty much everything the solutions suggest are already live in the config files.  So no, this is **NOT** a duplicate.

Okay, I've tired asking this on the Apache Friends Forum and got no response on how to fix it.  I've also tired solutions that I've found here, none have worked.  I have XAMPP for Windows v7.1.6, a fresh install on a new machine.  I've checked my php.ini file and the mysqli.dll file is correctly listed and not commented out.  I have started the MySQL server and attempted to access phpMyAdmin via localhost/phpmyadmin and I get the error message:

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
>   See our documentation for more information.

```
My phpinfo() output located at:  
https://pastebin.com/GL9FMphD
```

I'm trying to get this up so I can continue a project I'm working on but can't seem to get phpMyAdmin to work at all.  Any help anyone can provide would be wonderful.  If you want to see my full php.ini file, in the even that maybe I missed something, I'd be happy to paste that in here as well.

Thanks in advance for everyone's help!

Comment: I assume that your using the same PHP and not running both CLI and web based.  But check the name of the loaded php.ini when you do a `phpinfo();` to ensure it's the same file as your altering.

Comment: I should be, yes.  I found out the phpinfo() was too long even for a comment so I created a pastebin for it, here:  https://pastebin.com/GL9FMphD